# Running JavaScript with ionic 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

I have built an algorithm in JavaScript, now I wish to use this algorithm on my ionic 2 application. Ideally, I would like to avoid having to translate the entire algorithm to typescript. So far, i've had some success running javascript in the index.html page but can't seem to be able to CALL those functions from the .ts files.

Can someone please give me some suggestions on ways to integrate my js algorithm in my ionic 2 application, or should i just bite the bullet and use typescript?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: There is no reason to show the code.

Comment: Yes there's a need. We don't know how your code is, if it's pure JS or if it has jquery, how are you calling it on your HTML file, if you're using it in the right place. So show us the code so we can help

Comment: Sure, the code is here: "function hello(){alert('hello world');}" How do i call this function on the .ts files?

Comment: Posting code is redundant given my circumstances, trust me. I just need advice.

Answer (score 1):

You would need (.d.ts) **typings** definition files for this. For example:

If you have demo.js file with following content.

```
var setUserInfo = function (firstName, secondName) {
    console.log("demo function called: " + firstName + " " + secondName);
}

module.exports = { setUserInfo: setUserInfo };
```

You would need to make a [declaration](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20%28.d.ts%29%20Files) **demo.d.ts** file with following:

```
declare module User {
    function setUserInfo(firstName: string, secondName: string): void;
}

export = User;
```

Put above two files in one directory. Now if you want to use js in your ts file then follow below steps:

1). `import * as _ from './demo';` // first import file. Here ./demo path is relative to your current directory

2). `_.setUserInfo("sandeep", "sharma");` // call method

Hope this will help you !!